# node.js Bad CPU type in executable?

Tags: node.js

a friend of mine suggested I try out nodeJS for a project I'm working on. However, it would give me the below error if I try to open it via Terminal.

[image: NodeJS Error]

I got the installer from nodeJS.org. And I'm running under Mac OS X Snow Leopard. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: What is the output of `file /usr/local/bin/node`?

Comment: Compile it from source.  Works great everytime.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz where do I see that?

Comment: @JustinThomas I'm not sure how and I might screw something up if I do it myself.

Comment: Download the source and do: ./configure; make; make install;

Comment: @ShedoChung-HeeSurashu The way you saw the output of `node`. You type it in, you press enter, and then you see its output.

Answer (score 0):

At this point you should just compile Node from source.  It is the recommended way to go about it, it's easy, and it will work on your machine.  Directions are on the github page.